# Cannot see firebase data in application - react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a call to fetch data from my firebase database using react native.

**Database structure**

[image]

Code inside **FirebaseList.js**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: []
 };
}

componentWillMount() {
  firebase.database().ref('/signposts/items').on('value', snapshot => {
    const dataArray = [];
    const result = snapshot.val();
    for (const data in result) {
      dataArray.push(data);
    }
    this.setState({ data: dataArray });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      )}
      keyExtractor={item => item}
    />
  );
}
```

I believe the connection to firebase is successful as I can build and run the application. However, when the component renders, I do not see my two rows of data 'row1' and 'row2'.

Comment: Did you try to console.log dataArray inside componentDidMount()? And then console.log inside render()?

Comment: @Rahamin I don't see anything inside my console

Comment: Then try to check your connection... See Sample code in the answer...

Comment: The thing is you promise is returned after you data is rendered & what is `cloneWithRows`??

Comment: @RaajNadar not sure what `cloneWithRows` is, I used a tutorial https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

Comment: Try doing this `this.state.listViewData[0]`

Comment: Still, nothing :/ when you say the promise is returned after the data is rendered, how do I rectify that?

Comment: @RaajNadar I solved it - updated the code to reflect the solution for anybody else with a similar issue. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Make sure that you change the rules after testing and use real time database with auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your code is right then also check that this rules are set

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Note : - When you use the above rule your database is open for all [Read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). Make you use update the rules once you push to production.

Comment: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}` Changed my rules to this, stil nothing :(

Comment: Wait for few mins and than try.. If you just changed the settings

Comment: this did it, thanks a lot... I can now see my data in the console if I log this.state... Now to try figure out why it's not rendering

Answer (score 1):

If `console.log(dataArray)` shows an empty array (assuming that `console.log()` works...), try checking your connection:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const ref = firebase.database().ref('/signposts');
  const checkConnection = firebase.database().ref(`.info/connected`);
  checkConnection.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() === true) {  /* we're connected! */
      firebase.database().ref('/signposts').on('value', snapshot => {
        const dataArray = [];
        const result = snapshot.val();
        for (const data in result) {
          dataArray.push(data);
        }
        if (dataArray.length === 0)
          console.log("No data.")
        else
          this.setState({ listViewData: dataArray });
      });
    } else {  /* we're disconnected! */
      console.error("Check your internet connection.")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to include this into my code

Comment: Thanks, i'm getting an unexpected token error and can't see where from